# Instead of -1 i need NA in r

Tags: r

When i search for a position of a string in a varaible, Iam getting -1 whenever the string is not available in the varaible. How to get NA instead of -1

I used below codes

```
la2$aspx_num[i1] <-sapply(gregexpr("aspxerrorpath=",la2$dvr[i1]),c)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can change it to `NA` by either using `ifelse/replace` by using `==` or

```
r1 <- sapply(gregexpr("as", v1), c)
r1*NA^(r1==-1)
#[1]  1 NA
```

Or using `ifelse`

```
ifelse(r1==-1, NA, r1)
#[1]  1 NA
```

---

Using the OP's code

```
la2$aspx_num[i1] <-sapply(gregexpr("aspxerrorpath=",la2$dvr[i1]),c)
la2$aspx_num[i1] <- ifelse(la2$aspx_num[i1]==-1, NA, la2$aspx_num[i1])
```

#### data

```
 v1 <- c("asd", "apf")
```

Comment: You could also use `stringr`. `library(stringr) str_match(v1,"lala")`